# Django startswith query

Tags: python, django

How would I do the following query?

```
SELECT * FROM title WHERE id LIKE '12345%'
```

What I currently have is:

```
Title.objects.get(id='12345')
```

Which obviously doesn't do the `LIKE%` (and the `icontains` does both). What would be the correct query here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Title.objects.filter(id__startswith='12345')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this where `code` would be your `startswith` string by which you want to filter the table.

code = '12345'
enter code hereTitle.objects.extra(where=["%s LIKE id||'%%'"], params=[code])