# Search string in database column django query

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a field in db which contains string like "Food,Financial,Health" . I need to search string which is startswith "Fi" in that field. I can search string using contains but i need to search startswith in django query. Anyone suggest me to do that.

Comment: you should search first, it's first search result if you search for django query https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django startswith query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740446/django-startswith-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use startswith in django query..

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(stringField__startswith='What')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the django __startswith filter attribute.

```
YourModelClass.objects.filter(fieldname__startswith='Fi')
```

See the docs here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#startswith

Answer (score 0):

```
Modelname.objects.filter(attributename__istartswith='Fi')
```

for more details refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/